# Using rand() with a NSUInteger to get random element from array

Tags: ios, objective-c, random

In an objective C script I am trying to get a random string from an NSArray by using

```
int idx = rand() % self.adviceList.count;
```

However, every time it executes it throws an `EXC_ARITHMETIC` error. My question is twofold:

1) How do I get the code to run

2) is there a more portable way to generate a random int/NSUInteger in iOS programming?

Comment: Most likely `count` is zero.  Possibly because `adviceList` is nil, possibly because it's simply an empty list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code you posted should work. Probably `self.adviceList.count` returns zero and this is a reason of `EXC_ARITHMETIC`.

As Mattt Thompson wrote in his [article](http://nshipster.com/random/):

> Use arc4random() and its related functions.
>
> Specifically, to generate a random number between 0 and N - 1, use
>   arc4random_uniform(), which avoids modulo bias.

Comment: But arc4random will likely also choke if self.adviceList.count is zero.

Answer (score -1):

Try using `arc4random_uniform( num )` which takes in an unsigned int

`rand()` returns an int and `random()` returns a long so it is possible modulus doesn't like unsigned numbers?